# Macbook pro (15) 2011 - display problem

Tags: macbook-pro, screen

I have a problem. I noticed when writing a mail today and the PDF invoice me flashing cursor - the slow and fast movements.
I am not sure what to can - you have a problem with that and you?

The display has been claimed (burned pixel) and then made ​​it even now - so the display is OK. Could it Software?

Mac OS X 10.7.3 LION - and made ​​it to 10.7.2

Thanks for the advice

/They have a problem with the owners of several MBP! - You belong to them and you? Thanks.

Comment: Mirec - I appreciate that English is probably not your first language, but I am not able to understand your problem enough to be able to provide help.  Can you perhaps get some help editing your question to make it clearer?  You may want to try an online translation tool translate.google.com

Comment: This question was originally posted to Slovak apple-related forum at http://www.macblog.sk/forum/discussion/29706/ Basically his problem is that while he writes an email or views PDF, his cursor is flashing. He had his computer serviced, but no problem was found and he is now trying to diagnose the flashing issue. Someone suggested recording a video with QuickTime Player, but flashing didn't occur while recording. Last message in the forum suggests that he found the source of the problem: Unofficial package for slovak spellchecking. (It's bit confusing even in original)